# Heartbeat monitor and unit testing it in javascript - how to?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, bdd, jasmine, heartbeat

I have a 'service module' that listens for periodic heartbeats (over socket.io) and then if a heartbeat is missed publishes an event on an event bus (Backbone.Events). Also if the heart beat resumes later, it publishes an event.

My unit test looks something like this:

```
describe('Heartbeat service', function() {
  var HeartbeatService;
  var heartbeatInterval = 1;
  //the server is expected to send heartbeats FASTER actually.
  //otherwise we risk false alarms

  jasmine.require(['services/HeartbeatService'], function(Service) {
    HeartbeatService = Service;
  });

  /*Since these tests use setInterval, it'd be erroneous to allow
    mocks to be overwritten by another test. Thus not using beforeEach()*/
  function createMocks(){
    var mockEventAggregator = jasmine.createSpyObj('Events',['trigger']);
    return {
      target : new HeartbeatService(heartbeatInterval, mockEventAggregator),
      ea     : mockEventAggregator
    };
  }

  it('should raise an event on the FIRST missed beat', function() {
    var mocks = createMocks();
    mocks.target.start();
    setTimeout(function(){
      expect(mocks.ea.trigger).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }, 2);
  });
  //..other similar tests
});
```

My dislike for this test is that if it fails then it is likely that the reporting tool will list the failures under a different test - since the actual assertion will occur outside the it() function.

Comment: I hope you are not monitoring real patients through javascript ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [SinonJSs fake timer](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#clock) to set the clock 2 ticks forward instead of using setTimeout.

Comment: Looks good, I will try it first and then soon accept your answer. Cheers.